Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'
I am using latest version of flutter, with latest version of Xcode, with latest version of android studio. I also have charts_flutter: ^0.12.0 but I am getting the error :
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                            3,9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/charts_flutter-0.12.0/lib/src/behaviors/legend/legend_entry_layout.dart:134:45: 
Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

I tried flutter upgrade, flutter doctor, but everything is right and up to date.
I do not understand why I have an error, and therefore do not know how to solve it after many stack overflow posts.

The error you are getting is due to using of an old package. the last version of that package was released 2 years ago and in 2 years flutter changed very rapidly and the text theme property bodyText2 has been removed in the latest version of the flutter which you can now use bodyMedium in palce of bodyText2 and as this error is in the package either change the package and use a new one. or open the file which is  causing the issue and change the bodyText2 property to bodyMedium. you can read about other removed text theme properties here

Indeed thank you. It seems that it is better to use another package instead of charts_flutter, right ? It seems outdated from my workflow versions.

yeah you can use other that would be good. if you solved this you might get into another problems because many things have changed over time in flutter.

Yes, these are exactly the issues I met. Would you have other libraries to recommend, that does more or less the same thing and that are up to date ?

you can use fl_chart or syncfusion_flutter_charts which are most liked packages for charts in flutter. and both are up to date.

how to change ? there is no bodytext2 property in my source code.

simple answer is to use fl_chat or any other up to date package.

You can use Use 3.0.0-beta.2 for fix

You can replace your charts_flutter with charts_flutter_new recent version.
Navigate to
AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\charts_flutter_new-0.12.0\lib\src\behaviors\legend\legend_entry_layout and find bodyText2 with bodyMedium. Issue should be solved.
However charts_flutter_new also doesn't have any update since 2 years so eventually it will discontinued as well, so fl_chart is current better option to replace charts_flutter.

Try the nimble_charts package. It's a fork of the original version of charts_flutter 0.12.0 but it's been upgraded to fully support Dart 3 and the most recent versions of Flutter. The copious widget tests ensure that it works with the most recent versions of Flutter.
